# Better introduction to voting for new users

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting, new-users

My friend started using Stack Overflow, but I saw that in his questions he did not up-vote any answers; apparently he didn't realize he was supposed to.

Proposition:

- Make it more obvious to new users that they should up-vote good answers (a bigger message about it, maybe? Whatever you have now, it's not working)
- Make a bot that automatically posts a comment on every "new" question, e.g. "*If you find the answer useful, please vote up the answer*"

P.S. I will not explain to him what he should do, so we can experiment on him ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help in getting me [Copy Editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor), but could you just phrase your posts nicely and save us both the effort? I end up deleting half your posts on a regular basis

Comment: Please explain to me why you don't like the bold text? I tried to use keywords to make it more obvious what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you talking about accepting an answer?

Comment: no, i'm talking about up-voting. he did not accept any answer.

Comment: the same goes for accepting answers actually... some new people may just be lazy/not bother, but some might just not know they can accept an answer

Comment: @IAdaptor - If you carefully examine the [revision log](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/74922/revisions) then you'll note that he didn't just change the bold.

Comment: @Pollyanna I do know that, but at first it looked like he did.

Answer (score 6):

Well this is a good suggestion. Let me suggest how it can be implemented -

1. When a new user asks a question, when he clicks on submit - it should prompt a link to FAQ about how to accept an answer.
2. When a new user has reached certain minimum reputation and is eligible for upvote, then during his next login, there should be a top bar pop up which would link to FAQ about upvoting. (just like it pops up when users get a new badge)

Hope this should do good to educate the users on upvoting and accepting answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is possible, but how about tracking how many questions a new-user has read that have 3 (arbitrary) or more answers. If the new-user reads 8 (arbitrary) or more questions containing 3 (arbitrary) or more answers then a one of those top banners pops up saying something like "Do you know you can up-vote good answers? Click here to learn more..."